# Download data and display it

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am developing an app in swift 2 but I'm a little bit stuck. I have a solid program that takes a unique identifier and gets a name in return, all the names are stored in an array. When I run my code I see the printed names but I while the names are downloading, I sometimes get a lot times the same error in the console, and then the name downloading goes on. Also not all the array content is displayed in the TableView.
This is the error in the console:

> ```
> `Marthe Tordeur
> Jorn Christiaens
> Yarne Leuckx
> Jordi Stevens
> Jonathan Essende
> Hanne Pappaert
> Bert Van den Abbeele
> Cedric de Smedt
> Hanne Delcourt
> 2015-09-10 17:26:33.934 ProfileViewer[1130:82460] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can
> ```
>
> lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an
>   exception in a future release.
>        Stack:(
>         0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051d79b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>         1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106dd6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>         2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051d78ed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
>         3   Foundation                          0x000000010574a3f5 _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79
>         4   Foundation                          0x00000001055ab23e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 31
>         5   UIKit                               0x0000000105a916e0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 575
>         6   UIKit                               0x0000000105a9e3e2 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1967
>         7   UIKit                               0x0000000105b16a54 -[UITableView _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 420
>         8   UIKit                               0x0000000105b34fef __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 2679
>         9   UIKit                               0x0000000105a97548 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
>         10  UIKit                               0x0000000105b3455f -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 475
>         11  UIKit                               0x0000000105b3f0f4 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 828
>         12  UIKit                               0x0000000105b3f1db -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
>         13  UIKit                               0x0000000105b15250 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
>         14  UIKit                               0x0000000105b47fa8 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
>         15  UIKit                               0x0000000105b30599 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 218
>         16  UIKit                               0x0000000105aa1a3b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
>         17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e5636a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
>         18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e4abd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
>         19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e4aa4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>         20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e3f1d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
>         21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e6c9f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
>         22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e6ccd4 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 224
>         23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c0a39c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 470
>         24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c09f78 _pthread_exit + 117
>         25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c08596 pthread_attr_getschedpolicy + 0
>         26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c06375 start_wqthread + 13
>       )
>       2015-09-10 17:26:33.942 ProfileViewer[1130:82460] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can
>   lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an
>   exception in a future release.
>        Stack:(
>         0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051d79b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>         1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106dd6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>         2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051d78ed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
>         3   Foundation                          0x000000010574a3f5 _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79
>         4   Foundation                          0x00000001055aaa52 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 49
>         5   Foundation                          0x00000001055ab314 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 245
>         6   UIKit                               0x0000000105a916e0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 575
>         7   UIKit                               0x0000000105a9e3e2 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1967
>         8   UIKit                               0x0000000105b16a54 -[UITableView _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 420
>         9   UIKit                               0x0000000105b34fef __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 2679
>         10  UIKit                               0x0000000105a97548 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
>         11  UIKit                               0x0000000105b3455f -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 475
>         12  UIKit                               0x0000000105b3f0f4 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 828
>         13  UIKit                               0x0000000105b3f1db -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
>         14  UIKit                               0x0000000105b15250 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
>         15  UIKit                               0x0000000105b47fa8 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
>         16  UIKit                               0x0000000105b30599 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 218
>         17  UIKit                               0x0000000105aa1a3b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
>         18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e5636a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
>         19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e4abd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
>         20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e4aa4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>         21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e3f1d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
>         22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e6c9f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
>         23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109e6ccd4 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 224
>         24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c0a39c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 470
>         25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c09f78 _pthread_exit + 117
>         26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c08596 pthread_attr_getschedpolicy + 0
>         27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000107c06375 start_wqthread + 13
>       )
>       `

```
func fetchTitle(identifier: String, completion: (title: String) -> Void) {
        let profileUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.facebook.com/" + identifier)!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profileUrl) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let urlContent = data {
                let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let websiteArray = webContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("pageTitle\">")
                let secondArray = websiteArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")
                let title = secondArray[0]
                completion(title: title)
                print(title)



                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }



    //print(newArray)



    var titles = [String]()

    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("titles", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    dispatch_apply(newArray.count, queue) { index in
        let identifier = newArray[index]
        fetchTitle(identifier) { title in
            dispatch_async(queue) {
                titles.append(title)
                array.append(title)


            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: The error message gives you the solution: "This application is modifying the autolayout engine **from a background thread**, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes." You have to apply all UI operations on the main thread with a dispatch.

Comment: and how do you do that exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Eric said in his comment, your code is trying to UI updates on the background thread, which is bad.

Change your code as follows:

```
func fetchTitle(identifier: String, completion: (title: String) -> Void) 
{
  let profileUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.facebook.com/" + identifier)!
  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profileUrl) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let urlContent = data 
    {
      let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
      let websiteArray = webContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("pageTitle\">")
      let secondArray = websiteArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")
      let title = secondArray[0]
      //------------------------------------------
      //invoke the completion closure 
      //and the call to reloadData on the main thread.
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
      {
        completion(title: title)
        print(title)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
      //------------------------------------------
    }
  }
  task.resume()
}
```

By putting your calls to the completion handler and reloadData in a dispatch_async call to the main queue, you (asynchronously) hand it off to the main thread for processing.